# Xamarin Android webview is unable to clear cache

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-webview

Hi I am trying to clear the current `WebView` session. It seems it  is not working.  I am calling `OnElementCacheClear`  method in my `CustomWebviewRenderer`. I can see my `WebView` is not `null`. This method is getting called... When I opens the `WebView` it still has the previous login session.

```
public class WebViewCustomRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
        CustomXamrinWebView formsWebView;
        WebAndroid webview = new WebAndroid(Forms.Context);
        protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged (e);
            if (Control == null)
            {
                webview.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                webview.Settings.JavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = false;
                webview.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
                webview.Settings.MixedContentMode = MixedContentHandling.AlwaysAllow;
                webview.Settings.AllowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true;
                webview.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;
                webview.Settings.AllowContentAccess = true;
                webview.Settings.AllowFileAccess = true;
                webview.Settings.DatabaseEnabled = true;
                webview.Settings.UserAgentString = "Android WebView";
                webview.Settings.UseWideViewPort = true;
                webview.Settings.LoadsImagesAutomatically = true;
                webview.Settings.SetEnableSmoothTransition(true);
                webview.Settings.SetAppCacheEnabled(true);

                if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
                {
                                        string dbPath = this.Context.GetDir("database", FileCreationMode.Private).Path;
                    webview.Settings.DatabasePath = dbPath;
                }

                SetNativeControl(webview);

            }

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
            }

            if (e.NewElement != null) {
                            formsWebView = e.NewElement;
                formsWebView.CacheClearRequested += OnElementCacheClear;
                Control.SetWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient(formsWebView));
            }

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                 CustomXamrinWebView oldWebview = e.NewElement;
                                 oldWebview.CacheClearRequested -= OnElementCacheClear;
            }
        }

        private void OnElementCacheClear(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            /*   if(webview != null) {
                   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Cache clear called ");
               }
               System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Cache clear called ");

               webview.ClearCache(true);
               webview.ClearFormData();
               webview.ClearHistory();
               webview.ClearCache(true);

               CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.Instance;
               cookieManager.RemoveAllCookie();
               cookieManager.RemoveSessionCookie();
               this.Context.DeleteDatabase("webview.db");
               this.Context.DeleteDatabase("webviewCache.db");
               webview.LoadUrl(ServiceUrl.loginUrl);
               //webview.Destroy(); */
            CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.Instance;
            if (cookieManager.HasCookies)
            {
                if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
                {
                    cookieManager.RemoveAllCookies(null);
                }
                else
                {
                    cookieManager.RemoveAllCookie();
                }
            }
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => new WebAndroid(Forms.Context).ClearCache(true));
        }
}
```

Comment: What is you site using to save the login session? Is it using a cookie? If you delete the cookie on a normal browser and refresh the page, is the user logged out? If so, you should be able to look at the `WebView` cookie collection and verify this is or is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (it is not `WebView` instance specific):

```
/// <summary>
/// See interface summary.
/// </summary>
public void DeleteAllCookies() {

    if(_cookieManager.HasCookies) {
        if(Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop) {
            _cookieManager.RemoveAllCookies(null);
        } else {
            _cookieManager.RemoveAllCookie();
        }
    }

    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => new Android.Webkit.WebView(Forms.Context).ClearCache(true));
}
```

Comment: Hi..Thank you for your reply...I tried but it did not work....I have updated my question code the way I am creating wbview and renderer

Comment: @pritam001 Maybe try using my code to clear the cache before running `webview.LoadUrl(ServiceUrl.loginUrl);`

Answer (score 0):

It might be an older thread but maybe still helpful to others.

This is the way I solved avoid to constantly having to close the app to end the sessions of a WebView.

```cs
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

/// <summary>
/// Delete Cookies and clear Cache
/// </summary>
public void DeleteCC()
{
    if (Android.Webkit.CookieManager.Instance.HasCookies)
    {
        if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
            Android.Webkit.CookieManager.Instance.RemoveAllCookies(null);
        else
            Android.Webkit.CookieManager.Instance.RemoveAllCookie();
    }

    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => new Android.Webkit.WebView(Android.App.Application.Context).ClearCache(true));

    // Refresh the current page by replacing it with a new instance.
    Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MyPage());
}´´´
```

Answer (score 0):

A xamarin forms implementation can work like this:

```
  //Your view
  protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        //your named webview
        ReportWebView.Cookies = new CookieContainer(1);
    }
```